# Rewrite URLs to redirect and add leading zero

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a request on the server to this url: in the date part without zero.

```
http://example.com/url.php?date=2023-1-01
```

Is there a way to add a zero to the months from 1 to 9 and redirect from htaccess

```
http://example.com/url.php?date=2023-01-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following using mod_rewrite near the top of the root `.htaccess` file.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(date=\d{4}-)([1-9]-\d\d)$
RewriteRule ^url\.php$ /$0?%10%2 [R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive captures the parts of the query string before and after where the `0` needs to be inserted. These parts are stored in the backreferences `%1` and `%2` which are later used in the *substitution* string to reconstruct the query string.

The *substitution* string (ie. `/$0?%10%2`) is made up of the following parts:

- `/` - Slash prefix required for the external redirect.
- `$0` is a backreference to the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. `url.php` in this case.
- `?` - delimits the start of the query string
- `%1` - holds the value of the first capturing group (parenthesised subpattern) in the preceding *CondPattern*. ie. a string of the form `date=NNNN-`
- `0` - literal zero.
- `%2` - holds the value of the second capturing group in the preceding *CondPattern*. ie. a string of the form `N-NN`.

Comment: perfect: question, if ever it was in a subdirectory

http://example.com/sub/url.php?date=2023-1-01

Comment: @Kaz25 Then you would need to change the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ from `^url\.php$` to `^sub/url\.php$`. Or you could be more generic, eg. for _any_ URL-path just use `.*`.

Comment: if the url has other attributes after the date, such as.

http://example.com/url.php?date=2023-1-01?date=2023-1-05&type=all&lang=PL&content=ls